# Subset data from a column turning into value or error

Tags: r

I am working of this dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/volodymyrgavrysh/bank-marketing-campaigns-dataset

I am trying to subset the entire data from one columns just to to include who said yes (last column 'y')

If I do this I get the following error

```
bankyes <- bank[which(bank$y == 'yes')]
Error in `[.data.frame`(bank, which(bank$y == "yes")) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

If I do this it turns into a value

```
bankyes <- bank$y[which(bank$y == 'yes')]
```

Whereas I am trying to subset the data just to show me who in the entire dataset said yes. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try `bank[bank$y == 'yes', ]`

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much. I'm presuming the use of which is incorrect. While I always thought which is used for Subsetting data

Comment: Which() is used for subsetting but not in the context of `[]`  ... it's a way of avoiding the bracket notation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function subset:

```
bankyes<- subset(bank, y=='yes')
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bankyes <- filter(bank, y == 'yes')
```